# Is it possible to add the power functions to Western Train Chase?

Tags: trains, power-functions, set-modification

I recently got the [Red Cargo Train](https://brickset.com/sets/3677-1/Red-Cargo-Train) and it's a great Lego set but a Cars themed train going around my Christmas tree would be even better.

Has anyone gotten the power functions to work on the [Western Train Chase](https://brickset.com/sets/7597-1/Western-Train-Chase) set? Are the trains compatible with the normal Lego tracks? Is the "magnetic car connector" at the same height and compatible with the connector on the Red Cargo Train?

Comment: Also similar to the [Motorising the Maresk Train](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/833/56) question.

Comment: You could motorize the train car. You just cannot attach lights.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [product description](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/LEGO-Power-Functions-Train-Motor-88002) on the LEGO® webn site, the LEGO® Power Functions Train Motor 88002, can be used to motorise the Western Train Chase.

The train wheels normally fit directly to this motor, so I'm sure that this train can be used on normal LEGO® tracks.

Looking at the instructions for both the Red Cargo Train and the Western Train Chase, I'd say that the magnetic couplings are the same height.

Comment: Looking at the picture it seems the wheelbase on the train motor is much wider than the Train Chase set. Maybe it's the pictures deceiving me again.

Comment: Oh, and nice find on the product description . . . that's about as good a confirmation that it should work as I could get. Interesting that it's not on the box or description for the Western Train Chase.

Comment: All train elements in the Western Train chase are standard ones, including train wheels and magnets. The construction of the front is certainly a bit different, but I've seen people replacing that by a motor (9V, actually) without trouble. You could also motorize the first waggon, which may be easier to fit a battery box.

Answer (score 4):

We tried motorizing our Western Train Chase with the Power Function box as suggested on the LEGO site. It doesn't work. Their isn't even enough power for it to pull the engine by itself. The battery box itself is really heavy. I wrote my complaint to Lego. On top of this problem, we also don't have enough curved track (despite the purchase of 3 boxes of track) to make a continuous circle. They apparently only offer enough curved tracks with their $130 plus City sets... I already had a train, so was hard-pressed to buy another when all I need is curved track. Sadly disappointed in Lego, they are usually awesome.

Comment: This may sound like a dumb question, but have you made sure the batteries in the battery box are fully charged?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, since, well, I haven't gotten the Toy Story Train yet. But with the Red Cargo Train the weight of the battery box is what gives the train traction. If you notice the wheels of the train motor have a rubber "gasket" that also helps with traction. And the Red Cargo Train is able to pull or push just about anything I put on the tracks. The magnets between cars break apart long before the power of the train gives out. I almost think you have a dud train motor.

Comment: Oh, and if you do have a dud motor I'm sure Lego will replace it. Not sure how you prove it but give them time and they'll respond to an email.