# What is the difference between train motors 88002 and 10153?

Tags: power-functions, trains, motor, set-modification

I want to motorize my Santa Fe Super Chief. 
Its original instruction mentions [5300](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=5300-1) but it's marked obsolete on BS.com and now re-released as [10153](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=10153-1).

In the same time [88002](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=88002-1) costs few times less, e.g. $15 on Lego.com vs $55 on eBay.

So does it make sense to acquire more expensive 10153, or can just go for 88002? Are they compatible? What is the difference?

**Update:** Is the key difference in the way how does engine receive electricity? From metal tracks or inner engine (like Red Cargo train does)?

Comment: Similar to [add the power functions to Western Train Chase](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/833/56) and [What parts are really required to motorize 10219 Maersk Train](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/814/56)

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid: You're right, thanks. But actually I'm trying to figure out what the difference between this two approaches. Seems that 1st is engine-inside-wheels, and 2nd - separated. Something like that.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid: I've updated my question to be more clear and specific.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

5300 and 10153 are from the former 9V train system and drew power from the metal tracks. They were controlled using a transformer attached to the tracks.

88002 runs on battery power from an onboard battery box. Trains with this kind of motor can run at a set speed, or can be controlled by adding IR remote controllers.

Regarding compatibility, the 5300 and 10153 require powered 9V track. They will not run on the new plastic tracks. The 88002 is the same gauge as these 9V motors, so it will fit and run on the 9V tracks.

LEGO is no longer making 9V train components.

Comment: Thanks! That were my thoughts, wanted to confirm. But how to treat trains that expects old on-track power? Hack it's construction and install PF engine + wheelpair?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the specific 9V trains to know how well this would work. I think the main issue would be accommodating the battery box.